# postgresql : regexp_substr - get sub string between occurrence of delimiters

Tags: postgresql, regexp-substr

I have these strings:

```
[{"Name":"id","Value":"Window_Ex_kebklipecbcegiocpa_widget_open"
[{"Name":"id","Value":"Window_Ex_kebklipecbcegiocpa_widget_close"
[{"Name":"id","Value":"Window_Ex_kebklipecbcegiocpa_widget_mid_value"
```

and I'm trying to extract only the parts after the third `_`, until the end of the string (which ends always with `"`)

```
widget_open
widget_close
widget_mid_value
```

I'm using postgresql, and wanted to use the regexp_substr syntax, in order to extract it.
Thanks!

Comment: Show us what you tried and why that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `regexp_replace(data::text,'^([^_]+_){3}','')`

You can try

```sql
select regexp_replace(data::text,'^([^_]+_){3}','')
  from (
      select 'one_two_three_four  s'::text as data 
      union select 'a_bb_ccc_dddd_eeee_ffff'
  ) data
```

[image]